# encrypt using node.js crypto aes256 and decrypt using python2.7 PyCrypto

Tags: python, node.js, cryptography, pycrypto

I am trying to encrypt using node.js as follows (node.js v0.10.33):

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var assert = require('assert');

var algorithm = 'aes256'; // or any other algorithm supported by OpenSSL
var key = 'mykey';
var text = 'this-needs-to-be-encrypted';

var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, key);  
var encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');
console.log('encrypted', encrypted, encrypted.length)
/*
var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, key);
try {
    var decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
} catch (e) {
    console.error('Couldnt decipher encrypted text. Invalid key provided', e)
} finally {
    assert.equal(decrypted, text);
}
*/
```

How can I decrypt the encrypted text using `PyCrypto (v2.6.1) on py2.7`?

Comment: Basically the same answer as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27971983/1816580).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using `crypto.createCipheriv` as stated in https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password.

The answer below assumes you change your snippet to use  `crypto.createCipheriv`, as following:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var assert = require('assert');

var algorithm = 'aes256'; // or any other algorithm supported by OpenSSL
var key = '00000000000000000000000000000000';
var iv = '0000000000000000';
var text = 'this-needs-to-be-encrypted';

var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);  
var encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');
console.log('encrypted', encrypted, encrypted.length)
```

which generates the encrypted text `b88e5f69c7bd5cd67c9c12b9ad73e8c1ca948ab26da01e6dad0e7f95448e79f4`.

Python Solution with explicit key and IV:

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

BS = 16
def pad(data):
    padding = BS - len(data) % BS
    return data + padding * chr(padding)

def unpad(data):
    return data[0:-ord(data[-1])]

def decrypt_node(hex_data, key='0'*32, iv='0'*16):
    data = ''.join(map(chr, bytearray.fromhex(hex_data)))
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(aes.decrypt(data))

def encrypt_node(data, key='0'*32, iv='0'*16):
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return aes.encrypt(pad(data)).encode('hex')

print(encrypt_node('this-needs-to-be-encrypted'))
print(decrypt_node('b88e5f69c7bd5cd67c9c12b9ad73e8c1ca948ab26da01e6dad0e7f95448e79f4'))
```

If you keep using plain `crypto.createCipher` you will need to derive the `key` and `iv` from the password using https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html.

Comment: Thanks for this! Just a heads up that the openssl link is out of date. It's now at https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html. I found a simple python script to do this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42766835. But, as you point out, better to use `crypto.createCipheriv` in Node.

Comment: @jcasner Thanks, I updated the answer with the new link.