# Encrypt using AES-256 like OpenSSL with PyCrypto

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, pycrypto

I'm trying to encrypt a timestamp using AES-256 and Python with base64. The OpenSSL equivalent of the output is generated with this command:

```
openssl enc -aes256 -pass pass:'1Lw2*kx18#AvNuij*iRL1nY1UA_#k8$+' -nosalt -base64 <<< "1489355323"
```

My python code looks like so:

```
import time
from base64 import b64encode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = '1Lw2*kx18#AvNuij*iRL1nY1UA_#k8$+'
timestamp = "1489355323"

BS = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
iv = "\x00" * 16

aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
ciphertext = aes.encrypt( pad( timestamp ) )

print b64encode(ciphertext)
```

Currently the output is different, and I need to get the same output as the OpenSSL command. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What crypto library are you using?

Comment: pycrypt. I updated my code to contain imports

Comment: I feel like this is a password-vs-key issue, but I can't play with it as I can't access the PyCrypto docs at the moment. Maybe try using the `-K` and `-iv` options in openssl instead of `-pass` and see if that matches up?

Comment: Unfortunately the openssl command has to stay as it is. I can only update the python code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key and iv that the OpenSSL `enc` command use are derived from the password by the [`EVP_BytesToKey`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:EVP_BytesToKey(3)) function. You will need to reproduce that function to get your code to behave the same way.

In Python it might look like:

```
from hashlib import md5

# ...

last = ''
bytes = ''

# 32 byte key (256 bits) + 16 byte IV = 48 bytes needed
while len(bytes) < 48:
    last = md5(last + password).digest()
    bytes += last

key = bytes[0:32]
iv = bytes[32:48]

# ...

aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
ciphertext = aes.encrypt( pad( timestamp ) )
```

This scheme isn’t really recommended anymore, but the `enc` command still uses it. I believe OpenSSL is looking at providing a more up to date key derivation function in the future.

You also need to take care with newlines. The here string (`<<<`) adds a newline to the end of the string, you would need to add that to the string you are encrypting to get identical results:

```
timestamp = "1489355323\n"
```

Comment: +1 Also of note that you can add the `-P` option to `openssl enc` to see what key and IV it derived for a particular command.

Comment: In python 3.7, you will need to tweak this slightly. `last` and `bytes` should be initialized as `b''` instead of `''` and you will probably need to change `+ password` to be `+ password.encode('utf-8')`. Otherwise, you will get a `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`

Comment: Awesome! you made my day BRUO