# Corresponding AES encrypt/decrypt from JavaScript to Python

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, cryptography, aes

Recently I want to port the original Javascript AES256 encryption code to Python, I've seen lots of posts (e.g. [*1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236761/aes-encryption-with-crypto-node-js-decryption-with-pycrypto-python), [*2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156474/encrypt-using-node-js-crypto-aes256-and-decrypt-using-python2-7-pycrypto)) , but that's not I want.

I want a simple function without extra settings, only input the **payload** and **key**, output the **encrypted/decrypted payload**, corresponding to the below two functions.

```
function encrypt (payload, key) {
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes256', key)
  var encryptedPayload = cipher.update(payload, 'utf8', 'hex')
  encryptedPayload += cipher.final('hex')
  return encryptedPayload
}

function decrypt (payload, key) {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes256', key)
  let decryptedPayload = decipher.update(payload, 'hex', 'utf8')
  decryptedPayload += decipher.final('utf8')
  return decryptedPayload
}
```

I cannot find any solution to this. Does that mean this problem is difficult or the spec mismatch between Javascript and Python's library?

Or if I want to make it happened, can I contribute to PyCrypto or some open source?

Thanks!

Comment: Just use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor)